# simple node api restfull , get method by id from array

Tags: node.js, express, restful-architecture

I've written a simple api to retrieve records with GET  /tours/:id. It's works when I write the id on the url. Ex: /tours/0 , but not if I write on the browser just "/tours" , or tours/"

I've had  to write an another block to get the complete array with GET: /toursall , or it's not right use an onlye function to get all the records and by id in the same function?, I've update the code that i've found on a book. I'm using node 6.7.0 and express ~4.0.0

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
// custom 404 page

var tours = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Hood River', price: 99.99 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Oregon Coast', price: 149.95 },
];


app.get('/toursall', function(req, res) {

    res.json(tours);
});


app.get('/tours/:id', function(req, res) {
   responsetours = req.params.id !== undefined ?
       tours.filter(     function(obj)   {return obj.id== req.params.id} )
       : tours;
   res.json(responsetours );
});


app.use(function(req, res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 - Not Found');
});
// custom 500 page
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(500);
    res.send('500 - Server Error');
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log( 'Express started on http://localhost:' +
        app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.' );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `?` at the end for an optional param as below,

```
app.get('/tours/:id?', function(req, res) {
   responsetours = req.params.id !== undefined ?
       tours.filter(     function(obj)   {return obj.id== req.params.id} )
       : tours;
   res.json(responsetours );
});
```

Comment: it's a good practice to have one function for alls records and one record?

Comment: Based on the requirement. If it's really a simple on as yours, you can have one generic function. But if you need more manipulation/external calls then, you can separate them in two different calls. Infact, if you retrieve it from database like mongodb, it would be good if you have separate calls one for `findOne` and another one for `find`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `app.get('/toursall', function(req, res) {` => `app.get('/tour', function(req, res) {`. You REST API will be more consistens.
2. Hardcoded arrays are not the best solution, if you have thousands elements. Maybe, you need to store your data in database, for example in MongoDB.
3. If you don't need database, then use json file for tours and make `var tours = require('./tours.json');`

Comment: thanks galk, i had to choose the another response because my first problem was to understand about the parameters, i'm just practicing basis of node and express, before to work with db and real structures.